# Extracting a number before a pattern

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file containing a sequence like this one (a PGN file used in chess notation if you wonder):

```
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nc3 d6 4. d4 a6 5. Bc4 Be6 6. Bxe6 fxe6 7. Be3 Nc6 8. a3 h6 9. Qd3 Qd7 10. b4 b6 11. d5 exd5 12. Nxd5 Ne7 13. c4 Nexd5 14. exd5 e4 15. Qe2 exf3 16. Qxf3 O-O-O 17. O-O Re8 18. h3 Kb8 19. a4 Be7 20. b5 a5 21. Bd4 Ref8 22. Rfe1 Ne8 23. Qe3 Rf7 24. Qe6 Bd8 25. Re3 Re7 26.
Qxd7 Rxd7 27. Rae1 Nf6 28. g4 g5 29. Re6 Rf7 30. Kg2 h5 31. f3
```

Notice it is split in several lines. Now, from this file, which is continually updated, I'd like to extract the number before the last dot, in this case `31`.

I have managed to extract the last line only and remove possible blank lines with:

```
sed '/^ *$/d' thefile.pgn | tail -1
```

However, I have no clue as how to capture the last number before the dot. Is there a tool (awk, sed, grep, whathaveyou) that could do the job?

Comment: what's the output you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file consists just in one line, you can use `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]+)\. \w+$/\1/' file
31
```

This matches all the line and catches the last block of numbers before the end of line. Then, it prints it back with `\1`.

If the file contains many lines, let's go for `grep`:

```
grep -Po " \K[0-9]+(?=\.)" file
```

With this, you can get all the numbers in a different line. To get the last line, just pipe to `tail -1`:

```
$ grep -Po " \K[0-9]+(?=\.)" file | tail -1
31
```

It works by matching all the numbers that appear before a dot. As we use `-o`, every match is printed in a different line, hence the usage of `tail -1` to get the last one.

Comment: Your grep answer works but your sed answer gives me strange output.

Comment: @robohobo yep! Now I noticed your input file contains many lines, that's why `sed` does not work. I just updated with a comment reflecting that.

Answer (score 2):

This awk can also work:

```
awk -F '\.' 'END{split($(NF-1), a, " "); print a[length(a)]}' file
31
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sed` script can easily be extended to do the `tail` and `grep` parts too.  (With `sed -n` and a regex to control printing, removing empty lines is no longer even necessary.)

```
sed -n '$s/^.* \([1-9][0-9]*\)\.[^.]*$/\1/p' thefile.pgn
```

This is assuming the last line is never empty.  It's not hard to adapt to that additional requirement, either.  Here is a moderately more complex version which does that:

```
sed -n '/^.* \([1-9][0-9]*\)\.[^.]*$/{;s//\1/;x;};$!b;x;p' thefile.pgn
```

Lines matching the pattern are reduced to just the last number and stored.  On the last line, retrieve the stored string and print it.

Comment: I get this error output: `sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to s`

Comment: I fixed a typo but the error message was not the one you are reporting. Did you type a forward slash where I have a backslash?

Comment: I copied and pasted. Now it finds nothing. Weird.

Comment: Then the last line is empty?

Comment: Yes. It may end up empty on occasion. That's why I need the `sed '/^ *$/d' thefile.pgn`

Comment: Updated.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! Hard to choose between the answers. This was my version:

```
sed -e 's/\*//' -e '/^ *$/d' thefile.p | tail -1 | awk '{print $(NF-1)}' FS='[ .]+'
```

I accept fedorqui's answer because it is more elegant.

Comment: You could reduce to just `awk FS='[ .]+' '/[^*]/{ p=$(NF-1) } END { print p }' thefile.pgn`